# How to test if a React Component adds a style attribute to an element

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a React Component that uses a callback ref to store a reference to a DOM element so it can dynamically add a style. I'd like to make a test to check that a style is added.

How can I do this? I can see that the method that sets the style is called and seems to work as expected (because it logs a number). But when I log wrapper.debug() I can't see any style attribute.

What's the right way to add a test for my second it() function?

```
/* 
 *  Component I want to test 
 */ 

import React from 'react';

class DomStyleTest extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.addStyleToElement();
    }

    myElement = null;

    getRefToElement = element => {
        this.myElement = element;
    };

    addStyleToElement() {
        if (this.myElement) {
            this.myElement.style.height = `${window.innerHeight -
            this.myElement.getBoundingClientRect().top}px`;
        }
        _console.log(`height is ${this.myElement.style.height}`); // WORKS -- shows '768px'
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div
            ref={this.getRefToElement}
            className="widget"
          >
            <div className="widget-stuff">
                Hello, this is a widget.
            </div>
          </div>
      );
    }
}
export default DomStyleTest;
```

The test, written for Jest and Enzyme.

```
import {mount} from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import TestThenRemove from 'test-then-remove';

let wrapper;

describe('Testing ref to DOM element', () => {
  it('calls a method for setting height dynamically when the component mounts', () => {
    jest.spyOn(TestThenRemove.prototype, 'addStyleToElement');
    wrapper = mount(<TestThenRemove />);
    expect(
      TestThenRemove.prototype.addStyleToElement
    ).toHaveBeenCalled(); // PASS!!!!
    console.log(wrapper.debug()); // Indicates that no style has been added
  }); 

  it('adds a style with height value to the dom node', () => {
    // expect the node to have an attribute of 'style'
    // expect the style to be 'height'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manually updating elements in React isn't a great idea--among other reasons, because the change will be overwritten if the component is ever re-rendered. Instead, try saving the style to `state` and setting it in `render()`:

```
class DomStyleTest extends React.Component {
  state = { height: undefined };
  ...
  addStyleToElement() {
    if (this.myElement) {
      this.setState({ height: window.innerHeight - 
        this.myElement.getBoundingClientRect().top });
    }
  }
  ...
  render() {
    // relevant part:
    <div
      ref={this.getRefToElement}
      className="widget"
      style={ this.state.height && { height: `${this.state.height}px` } }
    >
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that seems good. Once I have state, I can test with something like `expect(wrapper.state('height')).toEqual(768)`